Append AppShortcut Conditionally in AppShortcutProvider
I have created an AppShortcutsProvider containing a list of AppShortcuts. Is it possible to add shortcuts to this list conditionally? Or, can I add new shortcuts when an action is completed so that the app shortcuts are dynamically added to the system?
struct DefaultAppShortcutProvider: AppShortcutsProvider {
    
    static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {
        
            AppShortcut(
                intent: GoToBankTransferIntent(),
                phrases: [
                    "Open \(.applicationName) to do a bank transfer",
                    
                ],
                shortTitle: "Ordinary Bank Transfer",
                systemImageName: "eurosign.circle"
            )
    }

    static let shortcutTileColor: ShortcutTileColor = .lightBlue
}

I reported above my provider and would like to conditionally add at runtime the shortcuts to the 'appShortcuts' list
